# How can you center the 2 tables in any browser size, whether its full page or half?

Tags: html, css

This is showing 2 tables but it is side by side when its at full screen. When the size of the webpage change, one table would go to the bottom and it is not centered. How would you center the tables on the browser regardless of the size of the browser, so when its smaller, it would still be same size?

```
  #table {
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 0.5em;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin:0 auto; 
}
.row{
    float: none;
    /* margin:0 auto;  */

}
.col-center {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
}
.column{
    margin:0 auto; 
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center ">
      <div class="col col-center" id="table1id">
        <table id="table" class="table"></table>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-center-block" id="table2id">
        <table id="table2" class="table"></table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example that shows the problem?  I've converted the code to a snippet with a single row and single cell and they were centred correctly when the table wraps.  Would be good to see how it's not working for you

Comment: I mean the tables are not centered when the page is smaller than full screen. i added the css for my table. Im not sure how to show a example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [`table`](//dev.mozilla.org/HTML/Element/table)s are **already** perfectly centered. Let me show you.

```css
.table
{
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 0.5em;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.row
{
  float: none;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.col-center
{
  float: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
}
.column
{
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center ">
    <div class="col col-center" id="table1id">
      <table id="table" class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>title1</th>
          <th>title2</th>
          <th>title3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cell1</td>
          <td>cell2</td>
          <td>cell3</td>
        <tr>
          <td>cell4</td>
          <td>cell5</td>
          <td>cell6</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-center-block" id="table2id">
      <table id="table2" class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>title1</th>
          <th>title2</th>
          <th>title3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cell1</td>
          <td>cell2</td>
          <td>cell3</td>
        <tr>
          <td>cell4</td>
          <td>cell5</td>
          <td>cell6</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[<kbd>Interactive Code</kbd>](//jsitor.com/x8g-tSOEL)

Answer (score 0):

you can use media queries for your table for smaller screens . Example `#table{ width: 500px;  }`
`@media screen and (max-width: 600px)){ width: 100%;  }`